# Why can I SubGit can fetch SVN repo but not commit to it?

Tags: git, svn, credentials, subgit

I have used subgit to create a mirror of my Windows based SVN repo on a Linux server.
The install has completed and I have cloned my git repo which seems to have all of the required code.

It does not seem to automatically pick up the svn commits and when I try to push to my git repo I get the error

> svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials
> provided'

The config file contains the same user name and password as was used to create the repo in the first place and the code updates every time I rerun "subgit install repoName" so the credentials seem to be valid.

Has anyone got any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look to be a common issue and thus require a deeper investigation to find out what's wrong there. I assume that may be caused by a recently found issue in SubGit hooks; to workaround this issue add the following setting to the [daemon] section in the SubGit configuration file:

```
[daemon]
    javaOptions = -noverify -client -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djna.nosys=true -Dsvnkit.http.methods=Digest,Basic,NTLM,Negotiate
```

This should urge SubGit to use correct authentication.